# Postgresql Divide Operation is Incorrect

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to divide the following:

```
SELECT                                                                                                              
(count(1) filter (where status = 'Failed') / 
count(2) filter (where id > 0))
from tracking;
```

The data in the table looks like:

```
id  status
1   Failed
2   Failed  
3   Failed
4   Success
```

So, the result should be; `.75` but instead, I get the following:

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]
?column? | 0
```

If I change from division to addition, subtraction, etc., I get the correct answer, it's just division that is incorrect for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a decimal point:

```
select (count(1) filter (where status = 'Failed') * 1.0 / 
        count(1) filter (where id > 0)
       )
from tracking;
```

However, I suspect that this would do what you want:

```
select avg( (status = 'Failed'::int) )
from tracking
where id > 0;
```

Comment: Alternatively: `count(1) filter (where status = 'Failed')::numeric`